# python oop аргументы по умолчанию

Tags: python, ооп

Я хочу убрать у экземпляров класса обязательную передачу параметра shield. shield=0 не является решением.
Как это реализовать? и почему установка параметра shield=0 не является решением?

```
class Human(Person):

    def __init__(self, health, damage, armor, name, magic_resist, weapon, shield=0):
        super().__init__(health, damage, armor, name, magic_resist, weapon, shield)
```

Comment: почему вы считаете, что установка параметра `shield=0` не является решением?

Comment: как мне сказали что это плохое решение

Comment: вам попытались объяснить почему это плохое решение ?

Comment: нет, но кроме как установить параметр равный нулю ничего в голову не приходит

Comment: нет ничего зазорного определять значения по умолчанию. Я бы использовал `shield=None`. Но так же можно использовать **kwargs. Вроде доступно для понимания [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/482464/)